# Django ManyToMany doubt

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have this models:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length = 300)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique = True)
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(Comment)

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(Comment)
```

I know there's `django.contrib.comments` but now I'm writing my own comments system.

Either UserProfile and Product object can have a list of comments.
Is it logically correct this?

My doubt is: a *ManyToManyField* means:

- an object A has many objects B, so an object B has many objects A
- or many objects A has many objects B ?

Which one it's the correct sentence? Because if it is the first one, my models layout it's wrong, because (for example) a Product has many Comments but a Comment has NOT many Product.

Can you clarify my doubt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first statement is correct, for a *ManyToManyField* "an object A has many objects B, so an object B has many objects A"

Note that when you define

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length = 300)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique = True)
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(Comment)
```

There is a kind of implicit ManyToManyField defined on Comment for UserProfile, eg

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length = 300)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    userprofiles = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique = True)
```

In fact you can define the many to many table either way round.

As you've noted your model definition doesn't work with two *ManyToManyFields*.  What you want to use is a [GenericForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) which can attach anything to anything else (which is how the commenting framework works IIRC).

Something like

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length = 300)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```